# Executing code after all modules are resolved and imported in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I use TypeScript for my Express app. I distributed the registration of certain endpoints across several other modules. These modules import `main.ts` and register them (see `depFoo.ts`). Unfortunately they don't seem to be registered and because `app` starts listening **before** `deppFoo.ts` executed it's registration!?

What is a proper way in TypeScript to fix this Heg-Enn problem? Can I register a callback that gets executed once TypeScript resolved all modules?

- main.ts
- depFoo.ts

**main.ts**

```js
export const app: express.Application = express();
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("App is listening on port 3000!");
});
```

**depFoo.ts**

```js
import { app } import "./main.ts"
app.get(...);
```

Comment: Try to make those modules return Promise and after you can get all resolved modules via Promise.all and I think it would help you.

Comment: I just found `modules.export` which seem to be a good alternative to pass instances across other modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/11/15/node-express-typescript) tutorial gives a great explanation of the router style system with express TS. One of the cleaner ways to do it is to have a `routes` directory with files similar to

```js
import * as express from "express";

export const register = ( app: express.Application ) => {
    app.get( "/", ( req: any, res ) => {
        res.render( "index" );
    } );
};
```

and then in your main `app` file you can use

```js
import * as routes from './routes'

...

const app = express()
routes.register(app)
```

Which makes your main file a whole lot cleaner and your endpoints more modular.